# Atributes behavior according to the situtation in Django

Tags: html, django

I am trying to add some logic to change attribute in class block. This is my initial code:

```
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
        2022
      </button>
```

So I am trying to implement something like: if current year equal to 2022 it have to be: `class="accordion-button expand"`

else

`class="accordion-button collapsed"`

I have tried to add something like this but of course it doesn't work:

```
<button class="accordion-button {% if {{now "Y"}}==2022 %} expand {% else %} collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
    2022
  </button>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `{% endif %}`. And to use in the way you want, you should [store the value in a variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#now). It returns a string, so we need to wrap the compared value in quotes:

```
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
            {% now "Y" as current_year %}
            <button
            class="accordion-button {% if current_year == '2022' %}expand{% else %}collapsed{% endif %}"
            type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
                2022
            </button>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```